# Is it possible to get a sub-array of a std::array in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I would like to do something like

```cpp
std::array<int, 5> array1 = {{ ... }};
const std::array<int, 3>& array2 = array1[1:4]; // [x:y] doesn't exist
```

That is, get an array that is a sort of view of another array, without having to copy it.

Comment: In the C++ standard library, they get around this problem by passing pairs of iterators rather than a reference to an array. Random access iterators can easily be offset for a sub-range.

Comment: Except that then you are not telling the compiler the distance between the first and the last element. Without knowing you have three elements, you can't unroll the loop.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that. All standard library containers are unique owners of their data, and `std::array` is no exception. In fact, `std::array` is constrained to be implemented in such a way so that the elements are stored inside an actual array member of the class, which would make aliasing impossible.

There is a proposal for an `array_view` class that would represent a non-owning view into a contiguous block of data. You can read about it [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3851.pdf). I don't know the status of this proposal (the current C++ standardization process confuses me).

Comment: I thought that a reference (array&) doesn't own the data anyway.

Comment: @Slava: What about C++ Core Guidelines types `span<T>`, `string_span>?

Answer (score 5):

You can if you use valarray instead of array
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice

Edit: from C++20 you can refer to a continuous sub-array with [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) in C++20 provides a view over a contiguous sequence of objects.

```
std::array<int, 5> array1 = {20, 10, 35, 30, 5};
std::span array2(array1.begin(), array1.begin() + 3); // {20, 10, 35}; subview of array1
```

The underlying data is not copied but rather referenced, therefore care should be taken to ensure the original array still exists when using the span.

Answer (score -5):

```
std::array<int, 3>& array2 = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3>&>(array1);
```

Comment: Doesn't this violate strict aliasing?

Comment: @JamesRoot, it definitely does.

Comment: Violates it most violently. I can think of several off colour analogies I won't be using in a public forum.

Comment: This would rely on `std::array` wrapping a C-style array (in which case I am not convinced there is an aliasing violation) but the standard doesn't require that

Comment: @user4581301, I have been using this technique for a while and interestingly I never managed to make `clang` or `gcc` to produce a `strict aliasing` warning when using `std::array`. Perhaps there is something special about the internal representation of `std::array<T,N>` as `T[N]` that makes it work. I am talking about this code for example `std::array<int,3> aa = {{1,2,3}}; std::array<int,2>& ee = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int,2>&>(aa[1]); assert(ee[0] == 2);`

Comment: @M.M, maybe there is no aliasing because the two arrays point to different locations in memory, they "overlap" but they are still different. (see the code in my comment above).

Comment: To have clean code it is probably better to use an `array_view` class. It is easy to implement if only the interface of `std::array` is needed.