# Does simple overlap of memory in variables violate aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, c++11, strict-aliasing, stdarray

In order to have effectively compile-time-sized subranges views of compile-time-sized arrays.

I have been using this technique for a while and since I never got a warning or an error I thought it was OK.

```
std::array<int,3> aa = {{1,2,3}};
std::array<int,2>& ee = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int,2>&>(aa[1]); // subrange {{2,3}}
assert(ee[0] == 2);
```

Until I found these comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046533/225186

I can make `gcc` produce a warning with this

```
int aaa = 5;
double& eee = reinterpret_cast<double&>(aaa);
```

or this

```
std::array<int,3> aaaa = 5;
std::array<double,2>& eeee = reinterpret_cast<std::array<double,2>&>(aaaa);
```

...but not with the first block of code.

**It seems that the aliasing rules are not enforced if the two references are not exactly in the same address?**

---

Everybody seems to agree that this is at least UB.
Would this be OK? Or is even worst?

```
int aa[3] = {1,2,3};
int* ee = new(&aa[1]) int[2];
```

It would be perfect if I could say `int ee[2] = new(&aa[1]) int[2];` because the type of `ee` will carry the new size and I can use subviews recursively.

Can I use `std::basic_string_view<int>` for this?
At cppreference the only constraint is that `int` has to be `char`-like. 
(Which I think it is.)

Comment: Not sure it is that rules which is broken, but it is pedantically UB, `&aa[1]` has no object `std::array<int,2>`...

Comment: You're trying to overlay a smaller array on top of a larger array, which I think would be okay if it was just possible. The problem is that it *isn't* possible, so you are left to "hacks" (and ugly such hacks) using pointers or references, which makes it all wrong.

Comment: And as a general rule, if you need to use `reinterpret_cast` outside of a very few places, then you should take a look at your code and design and think long and hard if what you're doing is right.

Comment: Maybe if you rephrased your question, explaining why you want to do what you are doing, someone could suggest a portable way to do it.  I can't tell exactly why you want to do what you are doing, and I'm sure there is a reason...

Comment: I think you are breaking this: _"Any two objects with overlapping lifetimes (that are not bit fields) are guaranteed to have different addresses unless one of them is a subobject of another or provides storage for another,..."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: I suspect that if you really needed a std::array-like access to a sub-array then the way forward would be some sub-range reference object with std::array semantics. I could easily see the advantage in such a reference class, similar perhaps to the std::string_view.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can rely on std::array implementations to not have private management members. Yes they have to construct without exception, so no dynamic allocation, and they have to encapsulate and behave like a c-style array without publishing any other non-static members, but it would not be correct to assume that taking a reference to "random" memory will have correctly constructed the array.

Comment: @ttemple what I want is compile-time-sized subranges views of compile-time-sized arrays. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Would `boost::make_iterator_range(aa.begin() + 1, aa.begin() + 3)` satisfy what you need from a subrange view?

Comment: @DanielSchepler, It could, the problem is that the size is not compile-time. I need to know the size of the subrange at compile-time. But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: So, I guess still the `boost::iterator_range` template (which is fairly simple at its core) could provide a starting point to modify so that the `size()` and `operator[]`, etc. could be `constexpr` (and possibly the size is even made a template parameter instead of being stored in a field).

Comment: Depending on _why_ you need the size at compile-time, that may still not really be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::array<int,3> aa = {{1,2,3}};
std::array<int,2>& ee = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int,2>&>(aa[1]);
```

This **definitely** breaks strict aliasing rules, and an access to `ee` is **undefined behavior**.

See [cppreference/reinterpret_cast/type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing):

[image]

---

> ...but not with the first block of code.

If your compiler is not producing a warning, it doesn't mean that everything is OK - warnings are not mandated by the Standard. Compilers try to be as helpful as possible, but they will not detect all Standard violations.